# GridSearchCV freezes on windows with any n_jobs

Tags: python, windows, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm currently having trouble with GridSearchCV method from the scikit learn library. I've been struggling with it for a week now, and can't seem to work it out yet. It keeps freezing when calling it to optimize a linear SVM on the C parameter.
Weird thing, it happens not only when assigning it n_jobs=-1, but also with 1 n_jobs, so I don't thing multiprocessing is specially the issue. Besides, it works  fine when I feed it an X array of shape (2448, 1024), but completely freezes when I feed it with an array of shape (5202, 1024).

**Data I'm feeding it with:** float64 numpy arrays of shapes varying from (2448, 1024), which works fine, to (7956, 1024)

**Things I've already tried:**

- Using multithreading, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47929603/9699979
- Reducing the number of n_jobs to 1
- Assigning a low number of pre_dispatch jobs. It started computing the first few verbose lines, indicating the C it was fitting, then froze.
- Adding an if `__name__ == '__main__'` block, as suggested in  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2889#issuecomment-37311446
- Running the code from the terminal rather than from a Jupyter Notebook, where I've been working

I'm not able to run the following code, as suggested in https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2163#issuecomment-314524070 since I'm running my code on Windows.

```
from multiprocessing import pool, get_context
forkserver = get_context('forkserver')
p = forkserver.Pool()
```

Things to note: I'm fitting it with f1 function, rather than the default accuracy one, which could be an issue, as seen in these threads:

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5115#issue-100597083
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2889#issue-28205288

Here are some code snippets:

```
 from sklearn.externals.joblib import parallel_backend

 scaler = StandardScaler()
 X = scaler.fit_transform(fv_train.data) #traininig samples
 y = fv_train.axes[0] #class labels
 X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, train_size = 0.9)


clf = SVC(kernel = 'linear', probability=True)
scoring = ['f1']
C_range = np.linspace(start=1000, stop=10000, num=4, endpoint = True)
param_grid = dict(C = C_range)
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid = param_grid, scoring = scoring, cv = 3,
                    refit = 'f1', verbose = 42, n_jobs=-1, pre_dispatch=3)
with parallel_backend('threading'):
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify your code in the  `__name__ == '__main__'`, run it from the windows command line, but without using the parallel_backend statement. Specifying GridSearhCV with `n_jobs` should handle the multiprocessing all by itself.

```
clf = SVC(kernel = 'linear', probability=True)
scoring = ['f1']
param_grid = {'C': np.linspace(start=1000, stop=10000, num=4, endpoint = True)}
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid = param_grid, scoring = scoring, cv = 3,
                refit = 'f1', verbose = 42, n_jobs=-1, pre_dispatch=3)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Open your windows task manager and look what happens while running. Look at your CPU percentage, your RAM and look at the windows processes. Normally what you want to see is your CPU getting very high, and you should see several processes called Python in the list of processes. It may be freezing because you use full CPU.

Another possibility is that n_jobs has not been implemented for f1 scoring. You could try running your code without the n_jobs statement like this:

```
clf = SVC(kernel = 'linear', probability=True)
scoring = ['f1']
param_grid = {'C': np.linspace(start=1000, stop=10000, num=4, endpoint = True)}
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid = param_grid, scoring = scoring, cv = 3,
                refit = 'f1', verbose = 42, pre_dispatch=3)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the first suggestion and also changed the C range to `C_range = np.logspace(-1, 2, 4, endpoint = True, base = 10)` and now it seems to be working, though it's still taking a lot of time (~2 hs).
Task manager shows CPU at 75% and RAM at 1 GB

Comment: You could verify if you have multiple Python processes (task manager -> processes -> sort by cpu -> there should be several times Python). If this is working correctly and you have to speed up, the only thing you can do is reduce the size of your parameter grid or the number of cross validations (but they seem reasonable) or find a faster computer (possibly a cloud computer like on AWS or others).

Comment: Yes, indeed I do have many Python processes listed (aroung 6 or 7). I also thought about reducing the number of k-folds in the cross validation but, in fact, it is already much lower than I would like to (and than is recommended), but I found no other choice because of this problem. I hadn't heard of AWS, will check it out, but I was trying to upload my training to google cloud engine. Problem is, I need these results straight away and I don't really have the time to learn how to use it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the too large value of the parameter C. I once faced exactly the same problem myself, and it was solved by decreasing C. Note that C is a regularization parameter, there is absolutely no point in such large values. (Refer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel). And it seems that as C increases, the computation time grows exponentially.
In fact in my experience, values ​​greater than 10 will consistently degrade the performance of the model.